# question on least upper bound principle.

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Show that the Least Upper Bound Principle does not hold for the rational numbers.
This is to say, show that there is a subset S of Q which is bounded above but such
that there is no L ∈ Q which is a least upper bound of S.

Can anyone help me and explain this one please in detail? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $S$ of all rational numbers whose square is less than two.

Comment: It's evident that $\sqrt 2$ is a non-rational upper bound of $S$.  Proving $\sqrt 2$ is the *least* upper bound is the tough part.

Comment: @john can u please explain me in detail. that is already given in hint but i am not able to crack this i am new to this topic. Can u please help me explain this in a more detail. Thank you.

Comment: @rohit Let $T$ be the set of all rational numbers whose square is *greater* than 2; note that $T$ and $S$ partition $\mathbb Q$.  Assume $L = \sup S$ is rational.  By the trichotomy axiom $L$ belongs to either $S$ or $T$ (the other option is $L = \sqrt 2$, which isn't rational).  Now show that $L\in S$ or $L\in T$ both lead to contradictions

Comment: @Jon How to show the contradiction part?

Comment: @rohit If $L\in S$, say, then $L = p/q$ for some integers $p$ and $q$, with $L^2<2$.  This would be OK, provided there isn't a rational number between $L^2$ and $2$ (this contradicts $L$ being the supremum).  I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994169/prove-no-member-of-s-left-x-mid-x-in-mathbbq-x2-2-right-can?rq=1
Here it is right?